# Fuzzy system with AForge C#

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, aforge, fuzzy

Hello I making fuzzy system in dll Aforge.
I made fuzzy interference system and the problem is sometimes I get error from the library in exception is like:

`{"The numerical output in unavailable. All memberships are zero."}`

But my input numbers are not zeroes and when I build the similar fuzzy system in MATLAB I get output without any problem.
Does anyone some ideas where I should find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

> The numerical output is unavaliable. All memberships are zero

The message seems like an `System.Exception`, you can bypass the Exception by using the `try-catch` blocks:

```
try{
  // the faulty line(s) of code
}
catch (Exception e){
  // put something here if you want to do something if it occurs
}
```

Comment: 1: Catching base Exception class is bad practice, at least only catch the specific error you want to avoid. 2: This doesn't really address the issue, just says how to ignore it.